# Firebase CLI is ignoring my cloud function when deploying

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have cloud function defined in my `index.ts`. However, when try to deploy my cloud functions with `firebase deploy`, the Firebase CLI is not detecting my function.

Output in the terminal

```
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: preparing cloud_functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /Users/nils/cloud_functions (243.98 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: cloud_functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

✔  Deploy complete!
```

My `index.ts`

```
import { submitFunction } from "./features/submit/submit_function";
```

My `submit_function.ts`:

```
exports.submit = submitFunction();
```

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export async function submitFunction() {
  return functions.https.onRequest(async (req, response) => {
    response.status(200);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `submitFunction` function is `async`.

Change your `submitFunction` from

```
export async function submitFunction() {
  return functions.https.onRequest(async (req, response) => {
    response.status(200);
  });
}
```

to

```
export function submitFunction() {
  return functions.https.onRequest(async (req, response) => {
    response.status(200);
  });
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you wrapping cloud functions in other functions? The `async` functions return a promise so `exports.submit = submitFunction();` isn't the CF but some unresolved promise.

Comment: I'm wrapping the cloud functions in other functions because it makes testing a bit easier because you can pass attributes to the function, like a mock date.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase CLI only looks at top-level exported functions, and the only top-level in your `index.js` file function does not match the signature of any Cloud Functions trigger.

Are you looking for this?

```
exports.submitFunction = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, response) => {
  response.status(200);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have already found the issue :) It was that the function was async (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74333104/8358501)